# How to generate a new _rev in Cloudant/CouchDB

Tags: go, couchdb, cloudant, revision

According to CouchDB and Cloudant documentation, to update an existing document, you issue a PUT request. In this case, the JSON body must contain a `_rev` property. If this property/field is not provided, the update will fail with error **Document update conflict**. Trying to update an existing document with an incorrect _rev will cause failure too.

However, there isn't enough documentation on how to generate the _rev field when making the update request. The _rev field returned by getting the document would be something like `1-c8c95e64d4372b0c12c740a40109b87g`. In my PUT call, I have tried setting this to `2-c8c95e64d4372b0c12c740a40109b87g`, `2`, and other strings but nothing works. How do I actually generate a new _rev property for my request?

I am using Go.

Comment: Pass the same _rev you got when you retrieved the document. Its purpose is to ensure that you're updating the record you retrieved.

Comment: Great, thank worked. @BurakSerdar if you post this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the same `_rev` value you got when you retrieved the document. The purpose of the `_rev` is to make sure that when you update a document, it is still the same document you retrieved.